# How to manage multiple templates with it's static files in multipl apps in django 2.2?

Tags: django-templates, django-urls, django-staticfiles, django-apps, django-2.2

I have Multiple apps, but every app has it's own template with it's own static files , they server one purpose with different kinds of user and uses. the apps are:
1. Portal
2. Portal Blog editor(Its like an admin panel for the writer with analytics and stuff)
3. Main Admin Panel(Not  the django one)
I am using django 2.2 since I am running Djongo.
Please suggest me some solution on this problem along with how do i manage it's urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django supports per-app templates and statics directories.

1/ In each app, create a templates/yourappname and a static/yourappname directory.

2/ make sure you have `"APP_DIRS": True` in [your `settings.TEMPLATES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#templates)

3/ make sure you have `'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder'` in [you settings.STATICFILES_FINDERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_FINDERS)

4/ Then in your code always refer to your templates and static with the matching appname prefix ie `appname/templatename.ext` and `static/appname/filename.ext`